# MVC3 is valid email

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, frameworks, email-validation

Is there a built in function which will test if an email address is valid?

I want to test the email address structure is valid before sending a confirmation email to the end user.

I understand i could create my own function easy enough with the use of a regular expression but if there is a built in function i would much rather use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use

```
public class CustomerMetaData
{
    // Add type information.
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public object EmailAddress;
}
```

on your model. See more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute.aspx).

however, last time I checked it does not work client sided.

I googled it, and from [imran baloch's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/02/05/new-validation-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc-3-future.aspx) it seems it does work now.

Comment: I do not think the DataType attribute actually does any validation - last time I tried it, it did not (ASP .NET MVC 3) server side or client side.  I think it is just a way to associate a type with data.  The blog post you linked to does not talk about DataType, just some custom validation attributes-

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with Data Annotations extensions I believe.  Check out Scott Guthrie's blog post on it here:  http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2011/02/23/introducing-data-annotations-extensions.aspx.

There is a good point in Scott's post as to why you would use this rather than the MVC 3 Futures validators which might be relevant to your choice:

> ASP.NET MVC 3 futures defines four new data annotations attributes which this project has as well: CreditCard, Email, Url and EqualTo.  Unfortunately referencing MVC 3 futures necessitates taking an dependency on MVC 3 in your model layer, which may be unadvisable in a multi-tiered project.  Data Annotations Extensions keeps the server and client side libraries separate so using the project’s validation attributes don’t require you to take any additional dependencies in your model layer which still allowing for the rich client validation experience if you are using MVC 3.

Comment: +1 I have used this extension class. It has lots of useful stuff in it, not just email validation.